# How can I deal with a long className in React JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, jsx

Let's say I'm rendering this component in React JSX:

```
render() {
  return (
    <h1 className="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-5">Some text</h1>
  );
}
```

The classes trigger my JS linter as a line that's too long, and it's very hard to read. How can I separate a long `className` property in a React component into multiple lines without breaking JSX syntax or triggering a different error in a JS linter? (I'm using ESLint).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another Cleaner method will be to store the classNames in an array and join them.

`render() {
const classNames = ['col-xs-6',
   'col-xs-offset-3',
   'col-md-4',
   'col-md-offset-4',
   'col-lg-2',
   'col-lg-offset-5']
  return (
    <h1 className={classNames.join(' ')}>Some text</h1>
  );
}`

Answer (score 7):

I usually just wrap the strings to multiple lines and concatenate them.
Don't forget to add spaces at the end or beginning of the strings.

So for your example it would be:

```
render() {
 return (
  <h1 className={
   'col-xs-6 ' +
   'col-xs-offset-3 ' +
   'col-md-4 ' +
   'col-md-offset-4 ' +
   'col-lg-2 ' +
   'col-lg-offset-5'}>Some text</h1>
 );
}
```

This way you it's also way easier to scan which classNames you have set.

Here is a [great resource](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#strings--concat-perf) for some best-practice coding patterns, together with their respective ESLint or JSCS option.

Comment: Your code will not work since you do not have spaces between classes. 
You have just created one long string without spaces.

Comment: Yes! I can't believe I haven't seen that. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

@Imamudin Naseem solution with some code style improvements

I would suggest to improve code style and save classNames directly as a string

```
render() {
  const classNames = [
     'col-xs-6',
     'col-xs-offset-3',
     'col-md-4',
     'col-md-offset-4',
     'col-lg-2',
     'col-lg-offset-5'
  ].join(' ')

  return (
    <h1 className={classNames}>
      Some text
    </h1>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [classNames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames):

```
classNames('foo', 'bar'); // => 'foo bar'
classNames('foo', 'bar'); // => 'foo bar'
classNames('foo', { bar: true }); // => 'foo bar'
classNames({ 'foo-bar': true }); // => 'foo-bar'
classNames({ 'foo-bar': false }); // => ''
```

Maybe you can define some of your classes as variable, and reuse it.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest if there is some logic (decided based on some other values/props) to how the entire classname is decided you should use the [classNames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) npm package.

However, in your case it seems that the class list is known to you already. In such a case, I tend to use Javascript template literals which allow a string to be split across multiple lines. Like this:

```
render() {
    return (
        <h1 className={`col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 
            col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-5`}
        >
            Some text
        </h1>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Use Backslashes**

```js
render() {
  return (
    <h1
      className="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3\
        col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-2\
        col-lg-offset-5"
      >
        Some text
      </h1>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [clsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx) libraray is a good option.

```
import { clsx } from 'clsx';

// ...

return (
    <h1 className={clsx(
        "col-xs-6",
        "col-xs-offset-3",
        "col-md-4",
        "col-md-offset-4",
        "col-lg-2",
        "col-lg-offset-5")}
    >
        Some text
    </h1>
)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use template literals

```
<div
className={`"card-body align-self-center d-flex flex-column
flex-md-row justify-content-between min-width-zero align-items-md-center"`}
>
```

Comment: You do not need the quotation marks inside the template literal, since a template literal is already a string. In fact this may break the classes.