# Does having too much whitespace in class in html cause any problems / performance issues?

Tags: reactjs, formatting, jsx, classname, template-literals

I am assigning multiple conditional classes to an element in jsx. The line gets too long, it is not readable, so I break it into multiple lines.
Since I am using a template literal, the whitespaces due to linebreaks are also part of the resulting string.

The template:

```
<span
  className={`${classes.voucherStatus} 
              ${statusTypes.ok.includes(voucherStatus) ? classes.voucherSuccessMessage : ''} 
              ${statusTypes.error.includes(voucherStatus) ? classes.voucherErrorMessage : ''}`}
>
  {voucherStatus}
</span>
```

Which will look like as rendered html:
[image]

I think my 'solution' is more readable than the ones [others have suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36678059/how-can-i-deal-with-a-long-classname-in-react-jsx).

My question is: are there any drawbacks associated with creating a class the way I did?

Answer (score 0):

The only drawback I can think of is in the event that you try to use the attribute selector to access the class attribute.

For example:

```
<span class="classOne      classTwo"></div>

/* doesn't work */
[class='classOne classTwo'] {

}

/* this works */
[class='classOne      classTwo'] {

}
```